# Can breezejs pick up validation rules from Ef configuration classes?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, data-annotations, breeze

I'd like to know if it's mandatory to use DataAnnotations for breezejs ef metadata provider to properly get all configurations for each entity? Alternatively, can one avoid the use of any conventions or data annotations and instead configure a mapping class for each entity with explicit mappings and configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1) You can define the metadata yourself on either the client or server, instead of having it generated from EF metadata.  [See the Breeze Metadata discussion here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format)

2) You can define this same metadata on the client.  See the MetadataStore addEntityType method.

3) Along with either of the two options above, you can 'reinterpret' any json results returned from any web service call with the JsonResultsAdapter.  We will have an example of this out within the next week or so.  By default, this is done for you, but you can intercept the process.

4) Hybrid use, where some entities are defined via metadata from the server and some from client side metadata are also possible. Similarly, you can choose to implement a JsonResultsAdapter for just selected queries and use the default for the rest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'd like to use the metadata from the server but I don't know if we are required to use dataAnnotations or if we can use the entity config classes?

Comment: it seems like breezejs builds metadata based on some EntityConfigurations (code-first) like IsRequired(), HasMaxLengh(), etc... but also respects validation "buddy classes" (metadatatype attrib). Keep up the good work!!